# Multiple (left, cross?) JOINs in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I've got a following MS access (2010) database:

[image: database diagram]

Employee, Period and Operation tables are populated, and UnitOfWork table is blank.

Basically I am having some items being produced by multiple workers (employees). Each item requires multiple operations (each worker can do any operations of any item any amount of times). All operations have some cost, and I will need to generate reports of how much every employee have earned "this month", have he fulfilled the plan, etc.

I want to do a SELECT to see following: UnitOfWorks, for every available combination of Employee, Period and Operation.

In other words, **I want to SELECT all possible combinations of Employee, Period and Operation and LEFT JOIN UnitOfWork to the result, so I can input OperationsDone for every UnitOfWork**. I'll add WHERE clauses and ORDER and later

I thought CROSS JOIN would help (In MS Access it is just enumeration with commas), something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (Employee, Period, Operation)
LEFT JOIN UnitOfWork on UnitOfWork.OperationId=Operation.OperationId
```

But when I execute this query, I get a "Syntax error in JOIN operation" error.

I've also tried like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employee AS e LEFT JOIN
(Period AS p LEFT JOIN UnitOfWork AS uow ON p.PeriodId=uow.PeriodId)
on e.EmployeeId=uow.EmployeeId
```

These are only 2 joins out of 3 I need, but already with this I get "JOIN Expression not supported" error.

Any database design suggestions are also appreciated - this is a new database I'm designing and I'm a SQL newbie.

Thanks in advance!

Update:
I am also thinking, maybe I should try a subquery? Like doing a CROSS join (of Operation, Employee and Period) in one query, and then LEFT joining the UnitOfWork to the query result... but how do I do a JOIN "by multiple fields"? And how do I implement a subquery in access?

Comment: You should try using explicit `CROSS JOIN`, not with commas.

Comment: Nope, the explicit CROSS JOIN won't work in MS Access. I.e.:
    SELECT * FROM EmployeeId CROSS JOIN Period
For this I get "Sytax error in FROM clause." error

Comment: in general you will face a lot of these "not supported" errors in MS Access,. I suggest u use SQLite

Comment: MS access allows to create forms and reports quite easily on it's own database - so I don't need to write any application for the database. That is an advantage for me

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM (Employee AS e LEFT JOIN UnitOfWork AS uow ON e.EmployeeId=uow.EmployeeId)
              LEFT JOIN Period AS p on p.PeriodId=uow.PeriodId
```

Comment: Employee table doesn't have PeriodId. And Period doesn't have EmployeeId. Employee and Period tables can only be linked through UnitOfWork table

Comment: @Ubeogesh I had the restrictions wrong, I've updated my answer, does it work?

Comment: Well it does execute, but i only have UnitOfWork-s joined for each employee once. I.e. if I have 5 employees and 5 periods i only will have 5 records returned (instead of 25). The problem is that Period is left joining to UnitOfWork table, which is **blank**

Comment: This query needs more brackets for it to work with JET/ACE, no?

Comment: What's the JET/ACE ?
Yes, I've added some parentheses like this: 
SELECT * FROM (Employee AS e
LEFT JOIN UnitOfWork AS uow ON e.EmployeeId=uow.EmployeeId)
LEFT JOIN Period AS p on p.PeriodId=uow.PeriodId