# MS Access adding nulls across all values

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, outer-join

I am trying to add nulls across all of the of the outputs. So for my list 'Assets' I would like an entry for 'A', 'B' and 'C' - if there is a number associated I would like it to display but, if there is not a number associated, I would like there the be a row with a null for the number. (For all assets I would like 3 rows)

I have created a table with the entries 'A', 'B' and 'C', and created a join between this table and the query that does my calculation.  The nulls have been created but, instead of having 3 rows for each entry, all of the nulls are in one row at the top.

I used the following SQL:

```
SELECT Query.Assets, [A/B/C].[A/B/C], Query.[Number]
FROM [A/B/C] LEFT JOIN Query ON [A/B/C].[A/B/C] = Query.[Type];
```

Is there a way to force the nulls into each asset instead of having them all lumped together? 
Note: 'Type' and 'A/B/C' both contain the same characters - A, B or C

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a `cross join` before the `left join`:

```
SELECT q.Assets, abc.[A/B/C], q.[Number]
FROM ([A/B/C] abc CROSS JOIN
      (SELECT DISTINCT Q.Assets FROM Query q) qa
     ) LEFT JOIN
     Query q
     ON abc.[A/B/C] = a.[Type] and q.Assets = qa.Asssets;
```

Access has some string limitations in joins.  If the above doesn't work, you can do something with a cross join and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT q.Assets, abc.[A/B/C],
       MAX(iif(abc.[A/B/C] = q.[Type], q.[Number], NULL))
FROM ([A/B/C] abc CROSS JOIN
     Query q
GROUP BY q.Assets, abc.[A/B/C], q.[Number];
```

Answer (score 0):

This Stack Overflow discussion tells me that CROSS JOIN is not available in Access:

[Multiple (left, cross?) JOINs in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512693/multiple-left-cross-joins-in-ms-access)

Are there other solutions valid in Access 2010 to create nulls? Any other work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your requirement:

SELECT Query.Assets, [A/B/C].[A/B/C], SWITCH(Query.Type = [A/B/C].[A/B/C], Query.[Number], Query.Type = [A/B/C].[A/B/C], NULL) AS QueryNumber FROM Query, [A/B/C]